# Algorithm for visiting edges of graph in parallel?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm, theory

Reference graph:

[image]

I am writing a program which tests all the edges of a graph. The program can test the edges of a graph in parallel if and only if they do not share a common node. My problem comes from the fact that I must also have the option not to test the edges in the most efficient way possible.

If testing the most efficient choice of parallel edges on the graph above, Edges `AB`, `DE`, and `CF` can all be tested in parallel the first cycle, followed by `AD`, `BC`, and `EF` during the second. This leaves only `BE` left for the third cycle.

If I am limited to only two parallel edges at once, I could then visit the edges in a number of ways, some more efficient than others. For example:
`AB` and `CF` could be visited first, followed by `BC` and `AD`.  this leaves `BE`, `DE`, and `EF` to be tested one at a time for a total of 5 cycles. This is less efficient than visiting `AB` and `DE` first, `BC` and `EF` second, `AD` and `BE` third, with `CF` as the final edge for a total of 4 cycles.

Is there an algorithm or practice that can be applied to find the most efficient path of visiting a graph in such a manner? My graphs are of variable size and connectivity, so I cannot personally solve and plan them even if I wanted to.

Any help or direction will be appreciated. It has been a while since have had a lesson in graph theory, so I do not remember if anything of this nature exists. I am currently approaching this issue theoretically, and have not yet started to try and implement any sort of programming on this aspect. As such, if my question is better directed elsewhere, I would be more than happy to move my question to the relevant Stack Exchange site.

Comment: So it sounds like you want a matching 
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory) - on the graph. However, wouldn't you need to find this matching (or other partition of the edges) in the first place by analysing the graph? Is it ok to have a serial pre-processing stage to do this before the parallel 'test' stage?

Comment: I'm currently reading the link you gave, and it seems to discuss what I am talking about, yes. As far as the second part of your question goes, I'm not entirely sure what you mean and could use further clarification.

Comment: I mean that whatever method you choose to split (partition) your edges for the parallel operation will involve a traversal of the edges anyway, so I'm not sure how much parallel benefit you will get...

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate a bit more on what the program's goals are. The tests in this program are more of an abstract construct than a real operation, with the real goal being I am told how many cycles it will take to visit every edge. This program is a tool to be used when planning layouts for a machine that tests a block of metal, where the real tests will be done. I will update the question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is edge coloring:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring

If you color the edges of your graph so that no two adjacent edges have the same color, then you can do one cycle for each color, testing all the edges of that color in parallel.

Unfortunately, finding a coloring with the smallest number of colors is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still reading this, but it looks very close to what I want to do. I will have to research this more.

Comment: What I am trying to do boils down to coloring a graph's edges with more than the smallest number needed. The thing that makes it hard is the fact that I am trying to find the most efficient colored graph given a set number of colors. Not a lot of reading to be found on doing that, sadly. Thank you for your help, I'm going to mark your answer now.